# dnu publish - output

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnu

I currently have a C# web app project running in Visual Studio.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114649/can-an-asp-net-5-application-be-published-such-that-the-target-machine-doesnt-n) article which states that its possible to run your web application on a clean maachine that does not have visual studio or dnx installed.
Here is what I did with my project

```
 C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Myapp\src\Myapp> dnu publish --runtime active
```

This is the output that I got.

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta7-15532

Copying to output path C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Myapp\src\Myapp\bin\output
Using Package dependency EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency EntityFramework.SqlServer 7.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Owin 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29
Using Package dependency Mono.Zeroconf.Providers.Bonjour 0.95
Using Package dependency sharpcompress 0.11.1
Using Package dependency Ix-Async 1.2.4
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Memory 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Logging 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Remotion.Linq 2.0.0-alpha-004
Using Package dependency System.Collections.Immutable 1.1.37-beta-23109
Using Package dependency EntityFramework.Relational 7.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency EntityFramework.Relational.Design 7.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ApiExplorer 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Cors 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DataAnnotations 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Localization 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Http 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Net.Http.Server 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.WebEncoders 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14
Using Package dependency Mono.Zeroconf 0.95
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency System.Collections 4.0.0-beta-23109
Using Package dependency System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.0.0-beta-23109
Using Package dependency System.Globalization 4.0.0-beta-23109
Using Package dependency System.Linq 4.0.0-beta-23109
Using Package dependency System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.0.0-beta-23109
Using Package dependency System.Runtime 4.0.0-beta-23109
Using Package dependency System.Runtime.Extensions 4.0.0-beta-23109
Using Package dependency System.Threading 4.0.0-beta-23109
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 4.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.0.0
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Physical 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.CommandLine 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 1.
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Ini 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.JsonPatch 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Localization 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Localization 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Host 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.PageExecutionInstrumentation.Interfaces
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.Abstractions 1.0.0-bet
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.Common 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Html.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.FeatureModel 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.WebEncoders.Core 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Net.WebSockets 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.0.0
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Caching 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions 6.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Notification 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Globalization.CultureInfoCache 1.0.0-
Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Localization.Abstractions 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime 4.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 1.0.0
Using Package dependency System.Reflection.Metadata 1.0.21
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Routing 1.0.0-beta6
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.Internal 1.0.0-beta6
Using Project dependency Myapp 1.0.0 for DNX,Version=v4.5.1
  Copying source code from Project dependency Myapp
    Source C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Myapp\src\Myapp\project.json
    Target C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Myapp\src\Myapp\bin\output\approot\s

Bundling runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7
  C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Myapp\src\Myapp\bin\output\approot\runtimes\d
sts.
Copying contents of Project dependency Myapp to C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Ma

  Source C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Myapp\src\Myapp\wwwroot
  Target C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Myapp\src\Myapp\bin\output\wwwroot
```

My project.json looks like this

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta6",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Owin": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.29",
    "Mono.Zeroconf.Providers.Bonjour": "0.95",
    "sharpcompress": "0.11.1"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://+:5000",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],


}
```

Based on this I got 3 cmd files generated in `C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Myapp\src\Myapp\bin\output`
these files were web.cmd , ef.cmd , kestrel.cmd based on the commands in the project.json.

Now when I attempt to run web.cmd this is what I get

```
PS C:\Users\VmwareX64\Documents\Mandarin\src\mandarin\bin\output> .\web.cmd
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment' has been reg
istered.
   at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Ty
pe serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)

   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider service
Provider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider service
Provider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
```

any suggestions on why my program is not running ?

Comment: You are trying to publish a beta7 runtime with application that is using beta6 packages. Make sure that the runtime matches the version of packages and move to the later/latest version (rc1-update1) - even if there is a bug in beta6/beta7 the code probably changed 10 times over since then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can expect a published app to run without any dependencies, you should test whether you can launch your application locally using `dnx web`.

Doing so would have told yout he same error which is due to what Pawel said: You are using a different version of DNX on a project of a lower version.

You should use `dnvm` to select a beta 6 DNX runtime, and then you could publish a beta 6 application package.

But the better solution would be to upgrade to RC1-update1 since that’s the only supported release at the moment and includes a lot of bug fixes that existed before. Both beta 6 and beta 7 are really ancient actually and had a lot of issues which you want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out I am going to give this a try and report back

Comment: If I use the command 'dnx web' I get "please specify the command to use" ? Am I suppose to pase the command of project.json here ?

Comment: You need to run it from the directory where the `project.json` is.

Comment: I am running it from there

Comment: it should have been dnx . web

Comment: Oh right. That's also because you are using a very old version of DNX… You really should upgrade, better sooner than later.